# When a VOR is an IAF, must it be treated as a fly-over waypoint, or is fly-by acceptable?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules

I have a VOR approach at KMDQ that has you fly outbound from the VOR as the IAF, do a procedure turn and come back to the VOR as the Final approach fix.  My question is, when you are using it as the IAF, do you have to wait for the flip on the VOR before turning outbound to line up for the procedure turn? Or can you treat it as a flyby point and start the turn before reaching it?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what equipment you have in the plane. If you have DME/GPS then you can round out your turn before the VOR. If not then you will not know your distance, therefore, you must wait for the flip. No regulation saying you must flyover the VOR.

Comment: Thanks so much.  That is what I was thinking as well, but wasn’t sure